# Ruby: .grep with regex

Tags: ruby, regex, grep, escaping

I'm using a regular expression to replace all `'*'` with `'[A-Za-z0-9]*'` except when the `'*'` is preceded by `'\'` like `'\*'`. How can I ignore the case `'\*'` ?

**code:**

```
puts Regexp.new(val.gsub(/^\*/,'[A-Za-z0-9]*')) =~ str ? 'true' : 'false'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [**Negative Lookbehind**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookarounds) assertion here.

```
"foo\\* bar* baz* quz\\*".gsub(/(?<!\\)\*/, '[A-Za-z0-9]*')
# => 'foo\* bar[A-Za-z0-9]* baz[A-Za-z0-9]* quz\*'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by being more particular in your substitutions:

```
tests = [
  "*.foo",
  "\\*.foo"
]

tests.each do |test|
  r = test.gsub(/(\\\*|\*)/) do |s|
    case ($1)
    when "\\*"
      $1
    else
      "[A-Za-z0-9]*"
    end
  end

  puts r
end
```

Results for me:

```
[A-Za-z0-9]*.foo
\*.foo
```

The first capture looks for `\*` specifically.